# Can "english learning" be paraphrased with "of" preposition?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, gerunds, gerund-phrases

**1?)** Scheduled session of learning ***of*** English.

**2?)** Scheduled session of learning English.

I guess I understand that in sentences it would be "learning English", because there are subjects, but how is that different to sentence constructions with **subject-less action concepts**, **concepts names or terms**, and **planned sessions or actions, suggestions**?

Other examples of that paraphrasing I am looking for:

**A)** To do list (as list with points or array elements of actions for doing): e.g. English learning;

**B)** What I found in a book in it's table of contents: "Choosing Levels of English" (it seems strange without "of" after the gerund)

**C)** I'm gonna do English learning now!

**D)** Get English learning with fun!

I just have not seen anything about the usage of such constructions with gerunds and "of" preposition and related to gerunds concepts, and with either options of paraphrasing I feel uncertainty and strangeness in rightness of grammar

Comment: Hi, @Rattler. I'm asking what option of paraphrasing that and generally all similar gerund constructions (not in talking, but as scheduled note or concept or scientific term) would be correct, with one "of" preposition (like "learning of english") or without (like just "learning english"). I could not find anything about it and I always feel wrongness with either option

Comment: In a typical school, the subject is never referred to as 'English learning' but merely as 'English'. Neither will one hear 'maths learning', 'drama learning'. The learning is implicit; what else does one do in classes, on courses etc besides learn the subject matter? (As an ex-teacher, I realise that that's a silly question looked at from one viewpoint.) Informally, "I've got to do some maths / science / French ..." would be typical.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think the OP is asking if a gerund needs _of_ in a gerund phrase construction when it is part of a bullet list or similar i.e. "choosing _of_ level"; "learning _of_ English"; "doing _of_ something"...possibly this is L1-L2 confusion: the OP is defintely not a native speaker.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gerund with and without "of" preposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281046/gerund-with-and-without-of-preposition)

Comment: There are exceptions ('The storming of the Bastille', 'the Taming of the Shrew', 'the Wearing of the Green' ... – fixed phrases), but 'The V-ing of the N' is unusual, especially when a 'pure noun' alternative is available. Thus 'The baking of the cake' might be seen as a chapter heading in a Victorian cookbook, but just 'Baking the cake' would be normal nowadays. I have admittedly just seen 'The wearing of a mask is advised' because there is no alternative nominal to 'wearing'. It's a formal alternative to 'Wearing a mask is advised.'

Comment: @Rattler, yeah, significantly partially, when now I know that that addition in "of" preposition is very probably grammatically correct and the construction is noun-like with one way of checking being adding some article

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, does your post mean that: **1)** all containing "of" preposition gerund constructions are always formally correct and it's okay to use it in texts in limits when there will be subject-less gerund clauses or phrases; and *2)* it will be okay even when there will be subjects in the containing that gerund based construction sentences?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth **Wearing** in *''The wearing of a mask is advised'.* is not the same part of speech as “**wearing**” in *'Wearing a mask is advised.'* The former is a verbal noun (as you put it - "a pure noun"); the second is a gerund. This can be demonstrated by adding a modifier: the former will only accept an adjective, but the latter will only accept an adverb. https://www.englishgrammar.org/verbal-nouns/

Comment: @Greybeard Another test for full deverbal noun status is plural-forming possibility. _The paintings have been stolen._  'Wearing' fails this test. There are many different tests and many interpretations. I go with the Quirk & Greenbaum et al umpteen-point gradience of V ... N ing-forms, but not all usages are easy to locate along a cline. In any case, many on ELU and elsewhere have realised that the term 'gerund' is so ill-defined (different grammarians using it in various often conflicting ways) that it is best avoided. Plenty of coverage in earlier threads.